# Which is the proper way to detect if my app is running from Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I need to detect if my application is running under the Visual Studio IDE (2005, 2008 and 2010).

The reason is that I distribute developer licenses of my DLL, so I need detect if the DLL is running under VS to check that the license exists.

Currently, I'm using the [`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) property and checking if the parent process of my application is `devenv.exe`. So far this works okay.

*I'm wondering if this is the proper way, or am I missing something*?

Comment: I'm curious as to _why_ you would want to do this. Having an application behave differently in a debugger sounds like a recipe for debugging hell :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, I use this to distribute developer licenses of my dll. so I need detect if the dll is running under VS to check if the license exist.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, that sounds like a decent enough reason :-)

Comment: FYI, just because someone is running the code under VS doesn't mean they're developing with your dll.  Typically, most developer licenses only require the developers working with the library to have a license.  If you have 200 developers, and only 1 does any work with your library, then you'll have angry customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen MSDN examples use that, and I'm unaware of any other way to check, so I would say that you are doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a command line argument to the program on execution from the IDE, something akin to a '-Debug' argument.

This would be done via the toolbar submenu Project->Properties->Debug->Start Options, and typing `-Debug` or whatever argument name you'd prefer, and then checking for it in your `Main(string[] args)` function, the simplest way being with the 'Contains' function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   bool isDebugMode = args.Contains("-debug");
}
```

However, if this is merely to prevent developers from calling the DLL unlicensed with their own programs, they may be able to bypass the system by starting the executable from outside of the IDE, then attaching the debugger after your checking step has been performed... In this case, I would suggest an alternate route of licensing.

Comment: See the updated question. While this solution was okay for the original question, developers could now just leave off the `-debug`-type parameter to bypass the licence check.

Comment: Try checking for a regular license, if it doesn't exist, check for a developer's license?